# Convert Money to Double in PostgreSQL Query

Tags: postgresql, looker-studio

I have a table with `money` type column in my PostgreSQL database. I want to connect the data to Google Data Studio, but it doesn't support `money` type data.

is there a way to convert `money` type to `double` or `bigint` in a query like this or any other equivalent query?

```
SELECT todouble(maintenance.cost) FROM maintenance
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, but: [Don't use money](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most natural choice is `numeric`:

```
select 123.45::money::numeric;

 numeric
---------
  123.45
(1 row)
```

You can also use `integer` or `bigint` but you have to take care of handling the fractional part then. Do not try `real` or `double precision`, per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html):

> Floating point numbers should not be used to handle money due to the potential for rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `::numeric::float8` this to convert it. so it become

```
SELECT maintenance.cost::numeric::float8 FROM maintenance
```

you can see it in the documentation below:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html